# Bolt: Backend results in a page not found error

Tags: bolt-cms

I *just* installed a copy of Bolt CMS to try it out. I'm getting a fatal "Not found error"

> ## Bolt - Fatal error.
>
> - Class: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
> - Message: The page could not be found, and there is no 'notfound' set    in 'config.yml'. Sorry about that.
> - Code: 0

So far I have tried:

- Resetting the .htaccess file
- Changing my php version
- Checking for the existence of a config.yml file

I know I did the installation right because it was done with Softaculous which does it automatically (unless there is a known issue with that)

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

That gets displayed for 404s, but when you haven't defined a ContentType & record to handle it.

The default setting in your `app/config/config.yml` is `notfound: page/not-found` which translates to a ContentType of `page` with the slug of `not-found`.

Not sure about Softaculous, but when you first set up and you visit any page, you should get an install screen to set up your first user.  The error you're seeing should not be available until after that is complete.  If that is the case, I would look at changes you might have made to your `routing.yml` file.

**Bonus Extra**
Once you're up and running, you may find it useful to define a ["hidden resource ContentType"](https://docs.bolt.cm/howto/resource-contenttype) for the 404 handling.

Comment: I forgot. Putting the answer in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

I talked on the IRC and the answer was to edit my .htaccess so that it had a `RewriteBase` line.